# how to create screensaver app using cordova angularjs for android phone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

is it possible to create screen saver application using cordova and angularjs.

I am trying to create please guide me

Comment: mmm i don't think you can create widget with Ionic

Comment: ok..thanks for reply

Comment: did you figure it out?